# How can I add DevTools extensions to the Atom editor?

Tags: electron, atom-editor, react-devtools

I would like to be able to use devtools extensions like [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) to Atom in dev mode. How can I do that?

The official Electron documentation [mentions a way](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/devtools-extension) to load devtools extensions in an Electron window, but I haven't been able to apply it to Atom.

I've tried variations of the following code in the `init.coffee` script of my `.atom` folder, but they all fail with some variant of "This method you're trying to access doesn't exist".

```
# Your init script
#

BrowserWindow = require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow
BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension("~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/3.2.1_0/")
```

Which leads me to think I'm missing something. Is there a way to load devtools extensions from `init.coffee`, or should I try so other method? Either way, which is the simplest way to proceed?

---

Secondary question: I've also found [this npm package](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer) that provides a simplified way to load devtools extensions in Electron. Is it possible at all to use it in Atom? I don't think you can add node modules to `init.coffee`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your two commands/statements on the **Atom console**.

Open it from the menu: `View > Developer > Toggle Developer Tools`.